# Pandas: How to fill null values with mean of a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, imputation

I have a dataset will some missing data that looks like this:

```
id    category     value
1     A            NaN
2     B            NaN
3     A            10.5
4     C            NaN
5     A            2.0
6     B            1.0
```

I need to fill in the nulls to use the data in a model. Every time a category occurs for the first time it is NULL. The way I want to do is for cases like category `A` and `B` that have more than one value replace the nulls with the average of that category. And for category `C` with only single occurrence just fill in the average of the rest of the data.

I know that I can simply do this for cases like `C` to get the average of all the rows but I'm stuck trying to do the categorywise means for A and B and replacing the nulls.

```
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df['value'].mean())
```

I need the final df to be like this

```
id    category     value
1     A            6.25
2     B            1.0
3     A            10.5
4     C            4.15
5     A            2.0
6     B            1.0
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `apply` [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html). Then get `NaN` if some category has only `NaN` values, so use [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html) of all values of column for filling `NaN`:

```
df.value = df.groupby('category')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
df.value = df.value.fillna(df.value.mean())
print (df)
   id category  value
0   1        A   6.25
1   2        B   1.00
2   3        A  10.50
3   4        C   4.15
4   5        A   2.00
5   6        B   1.00
```

Comment: 'Great help. any way how can I do this for many columns in pandas instead of a single column 'value'.

Comment: @Mari - Use `df = df.groupby('category').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `GroupBy` + `transform` to fill `NaN` values with groupwise means. This method avoids inefficient `apply` + `lambda`. For example:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df.groupby('category')['value'].transform('mean'))
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df['value'].mean())
```

Comment: thanks for this, was trying to speed up some of my ETL workflows and this worked a treat.