# Unable to make float from 'nan' pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am very much new in Pandas . My code snippet is below

```
filtered_sales_user = df_sales_User.drop('custid',axis=1).groupby('runseq').mean()
```

Basically I am grouping `dataframe` by `runseq` and calculating the mean.

But for a `dataframe` below, where few columns are `NaN` I am getting below error.

```
custid        m1    m2  m3  m4  m5       m12       m13       m14  \
0    4894  0.637958  0.01 NaN NaN NaN  0.189322  0.211065  0.002590
1    8080  0.854400   NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.009367  0.065700  0.012541

        m6      m7  b1  b3           b40   b41  runseq  net_sales
0  Money_Funds  Growth NaN NaN  3.171390e+06  18.0      29        NaN
1  Money_Funds    None NaN NaN  5.551656e+05  15.0      29        NaN
```

`Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to make float from 'nan'"`

Now should I replace all the `NaN` using `fillna` to fix this issue. And also will it hamper my `mean` calculation .

Comment: You can use `dropna` instead, so your mean wouldn't be affected

Comment: So will it still calculate mean for the above example , where say for `m3` all values are `NaN`. What will be mean for `m3` then

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40299055/pandas-how-to-fill-null-values-with-mean-of-a-groupby

Comment: Replace nan values with average of columns is not working . Because some columns  consists NaN only .

Comment: Just drop those columns.

Comment: No I cant drop actually I am storing them for reference. So drop means no records and might cause anomaly .